# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit -887826. Please update ADT to the latest version

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, adt

When I click check for updates it goes through many Google URL and says no updates available. So I did some Google and later on checked for install new software.
This also don't work it says the dependencies are already installed. and I have later on installed all the build tools.. It is not detecting my SDK saying to please update? Help! Please!

This problem occurred when I updated SDK tools!

and yeah tried Https and Http too no use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update ADT to the latest version instead downgrade the SDK to 22.6.2.

The new version(rev 23) is full of bugs. I we solve 1 problem the another problem generates, I faced the same problem and this is how I did it.

[Google project manager recomments to use old  SDK 22.6.2 until the problem is fixed.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72419#makechanges)

> Please wait for an updated version within a day or two. Until then, your workaround is to do download one of:
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-windows.zip
>   http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.6.2-macosx.zip
>   and copy over the following files:
>   tools/hprof-conv
>   tools/support/annotations.jar
>   tools/proguard

So, after extracting the zip file you downloaded , paste(overwrite) its contents in the SDK to where it is installed. Then start eclipse it will work normally !

Answer (score 0):

Solution is: First Update ADT to 23.0 and then Update SDK Tool to 23.0

You have updated the android sdk but not updated the adt to match with it.

You can update the adt from here

You might need to update the software source for your adt update

Go to eclipse > help > Check for updates.

It should list the latest update of adt. If it is not working try this

go to eclipse > help > Install new software

Click on add

add this url : https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

give it any name.

It will list the updates available- which should ideally be adt 20.xx

Eclipse will restart and hopefully everything should work fine for you.

Comment: This also don't work it says the dependencies are already installed

Comment: setup new sdk and eclipse

Comment: Yeah that's the last option!